# Assigning model parameters after having performed grid search

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

How can I assign model parameters **after** having performed grid search?

Right now, this is what I do:

```
model = ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=10000, n_jobs=-1, random_state=0)

param_grid = {
     'n_estimators': [1000, 2500, 5000, 7500],
     'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2']
}

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
gs.fit(data, target)
logger.info(gs.best_params_)
model = gs.best_estimator_
```

I want to assign the parameter `njobs=-1` to the model. How do I do this after the grid search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the resulting model should already have `n_jobs=-1` as one of its parameters, since you have initialized the model to be so before passing it to `GridSearchCV`. The grid search will only search for the parameters you specified, namely `n_estimators` and `max_features`.

Nevertheless, in case you want to update the parameters of an estimator, you can always use the [`set_params()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.set_params) function:

```
model.set_params(n_jobs=-1)
```